# Is there idiom for searching something that might not exists?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I come from Bulgaria and we have a proverb that says (translated one to one) "You're searching calf under the ox." which literally means that I am searching for something that might not exists.

Example usage: *"Stop interrogating Mary already, she's obviously not guilty, don't search for calf under the ox."*

Is there idiom with same meaning in English as well?

Comment: 'might' it not exist, or is it very probable that it does not exist?

Comment: well depends on the context actually, sometimes it definitely does not exist, but sometimes it is used when something is very unlikely to exists. :/

Comment: *Boiling the ocean* is a good phrase for endless exploration and search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"On a wild goose chase" might work.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wild-goose-chase) gives this definition:

> a search that is completely unsuccessful and a waste of time because
>   the person or thing being searched for does not exist or is somewhere
>   else: 
> *After two hours spent wandering in the snow, I realized we were
>   on a wild goose chase.*

The [phrase finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/wild-goose-chase.html) has an article on the history of the phrase. Here's an extract:

> Our current use of the phrase alludes to an undertaking which will
>   probably prove to be fruitless - and it's hard to imagine anything
>   more doomed to failure than an attempt to catch a wild goose by
>   chasing after it. Our understanding of the term differs from that in
>   use in Shakespeare's day. The earlier meaning related not to hunting
>   but to horse racing. A 'wild goose chase' was a race in which horses
>   followed a lead horse at a set distance, mimicking wild geese flying
>   in formation.

Comment: OP is looking for something that encompasses searches that might be successful (though probably aren't) - a Wild goose chase is (from the perspective of the one saying it) completely hopeless.

Comment: If the assumption is that it's definitely there then you could use 'looking for a needle in a haystack'.

Answer (score 1):

**tilt at windmills**   [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tilt)

> To waste time opposing or trying to resolve issues that are imaginary,
>   not as important, or impossible to overcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Hunting the Snark**

This is the title of a [Lewis Carroll poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_%28Lewis_Carroll%29), referencing a non-existent animal, the hunt for which must be fruitless.